# Best approach to group people into teams using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Essentially there are around ~200 in this department. We are looking to create squads of 4, where each squad must be from a different team, located in the same city, one must be a driver (and the other 3 therefore should not be drivers), and all four people on the team should have similar preferences. These criteria are captured via a Google Form so ultimately we will get the relevant data we need to build out the conditions. My only challenge currently is that I am not well-versed in Apps Script so will need high level guidance on how to approach it.

Currently, I am thinking of storing each column in their own respective arrays and then using a For loop and conditional statements within that to try to satisfy all the requirements. For example, the first conditional statement would be whether the person drives, and if they do then put them into this new array (which will be defined). Next, check the next response and if that person doesnt drive, and has same same preferences, is located in same city, and is on a different team, then include them into that array. Otherwise, move onto the next person and check for those requirements. Once the group hits 4 people, set the values into the Google Sheet somewhere and then search for the next driver in the list and build another group using same logic.

Alternative approach might be to first sort people into 2 groups (based on the two cities), then within each group sort folks based on driver and add in the other criterias as well.

Regardless of which approach I take in terms of algorithm, would first storing each column into an array make the most sense, then managing the array values using various conditional statements.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function matchUsers() {
  //store each column into arrays for use later on
  var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Responses");
  var Alast = responseSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(Alast);
  var emails = responseSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var userEmails = responseSheet.getRange(2,1, Alast,1).getValues();
  var tmName = responseSheet.getRange(2,2, Alast,1).getValues();
  var team = responseSheet.getRange(2,3, Alast,1).getValues();
  var city = responseSheet.getRange(2,4, Alast,1).getValues();
  var firstChoice = responseSheet.getRange(2,5, Alast,1).getValues();
  var secChoice = responseSheet.getRange(2,6, Alast,1).getValues();
  var thirdChoice = responseSheet.getRange(2,7, Alast,1).getValues();
  var driveStatus = responseSheet.getRange(2,8, Alast,1).getValues();
  var arrayResponses = [userEmails,tmName,team,city,firstChoice,secChoice,thirdChoice, driveStatus];

  //clear sheets
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output").getRange(2, 1,20,50).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CitySort").getRange(2, 1,20,50).clearContent();

  //prepare arrays
  var edmTMs = [];
  var calTMs = [];
  var edmDrivers = [];
  var calDrivers = [];

  //loop through each row and sort team members by respective city and driving capability
  for (let i = 0; i < Alast;i+=1){
    if (arrayResponses[3][i] == "Edmonton" && arrayResponses[7][i] == "Yes"){
      edmDrivers.push(arrayResponses[1][i]);
    }else if (arrayResponses[3][i] == "Edmonton" && arrayResponses[7][i] == "No"){
      edmTMs.push(arrayResponses[1][i]);
    }else if (arrayResponses[3][i] == "Calgary" && arrayResponses[7][i] == "Yes"){
      calDrivers.push(arrayResponses[1][i]);
    }else if (arrayResponses[3][i] == "Calgary" && arrayResponses[7][i] == "No"){
      calTMs.push(arrayResponses[1][i]);
    }
  }

  Logger.log("\nEdmonton: "+edmTMs + "\nCalgary: "+calTMs );
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CitySort").getRange(2,1,edmTMs.length,1);
  range.setValues(edmTMs);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CitySort").getRange(2,2,calTMs.length,1);
  range.setValues(calTMs);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CitySort").getRange(2,3,edmDrivers.length,1);
  range.setValues(edmDrivers);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CitySort").getRange(2,4,calDrivers.length,1);
  range.setValues(calDrivers);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain about the detail information of your current script and the issue of the script? If an error occurs, please provide the detail information of the error. And when the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want is provided, it will help users think of the issue and solution. If you can add those information, can you update your question? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Please consider following [tour](/tour) to learn how to better formulate a question.

Comment: I have a few questions regarding what you are trying to achieve. What are the `choices` (first, sec, third)? Is there a different team for each squad? Or is each user in a team? If so, how many teams? What happens if some Squad is not completed? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas , the choices refer to peoples preferences for this matching algorithm. For example we would want to group people with the same first choice together, but if there are no people left we could group people based on their second choices. The real-world context of this app has a job-shadow purpose. So the person who puts option 1 as "HR" and option 2 as "I.T" means his top 2 choices are HR first, then I.T. Here is a link to the Sheet itself: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zquBPvXoj0BK8laSS4GUffWrK2oNEjRe8xwPhI-h_VM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a solution almost ready, but I need to know what's the importance of the Driver in each team: Does it matter if there is more than one driver? Right now, my code orders by Same city > Different teams > Choice 1 > Choice 2 > Choice 3, but it's not taking drivers into account yet.

Comment: @Jescanellas there is only a requirement for minimum 1 driver per group, but there can be multiple drivers in 1 group of course. Tbh, if we even get to the point where all other requirements are satisfied then I believe the driver allocation could be sorted out between the groups themselves (other means of transportation could be expensed in our case). Really appreciate the help! I've since improved the script further so I'll edit the orig. post with the updated script as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if this fits your needs. I'm pretty sure there are more elegant and efficient solutions than this one, so I appreciate any suggestion.

I tested the script with 34 users, and I got 8 teams of 4 and 2 teams of 1:

[image]

Don't mind the repeated names, they are all different rows with different Cities, Teams and Choices. I added a letter to some of them to differentiate.

**The script works as follows:**

It gets each user row and compares the City, Teams and Choices with all the other 33. It also discards the users that are already in a team. The priority is City > Team > Choice 1 > Choice 2 > Choice 3.

It will also try to force teams of 4 members, so in case there is a team of 3, it will ignore the Teams to try to find the 4th, but it still will respect the Choices and Cities. You can disable this by setting the boolean `ignoreTeams` to `false`. In my test, only 3 groups have 1 repeated team.

The script will never put two users from different cities in the same group.

```
function main() {

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_1 = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Members");
  var sheet_2 = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Output");

  var number = sheet_1.getLastRow() - 1;
  var members = []; //Each row of Members will be stored here

  getMembers(sheet_1, members, number);
  orderMembers(sheet_2, members);

}

function getMembers(sheet_1, members, number){
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    var values = sheet_1.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
    members.push(new Person(values[0][0],values[0][1],values[0][2],values[0][3],values[0][4],values[0][5],values[0][6],values[0][7]));

  }

}

function orderMembers(sheet_2, members){
  var col = 1;
  var counter = 0; //Number of Persons in each group column [0-3] 

  loop1:
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++){
    var loopbreaker = 0; //Avoids an endless loop if ignoreTeams = true
    var ignoreTeams = false; 
    var row = 2;
    if (!members[i].assigned || i == 0){
      var teams = []; //Array of teams of each group
      sheet_2.getRange(row, col).setValue(members[i].name);
      members[i].assigned = true;
      teams.push(members[i].team);

      loop2:
      for (var loop = 0; loop < 9; loop++){
        var value = order_params(i, loop, members, teams, ignoreTeams);

        if (value != null){
          sheet_2.getRange(row + 1, col).setValue(value); //Writes in sheet Output     
          counter++;
          row++;

        }
        //If the group is smaller than 4 and the loop is over, it will ignore the teams and start again in order to complete the group.
        if (counter < 3 && loop == 8 && loopbreaker < 1){
          loop = 0; 
          ignoreTeams = true; //Set to false to never ignore teams
          loopbreaker++;//The loopbreaker avoids an endless loop
        } else if (counter == 3 || loop == 8){
          col++;
          counter = 0;
          break loop2;
        }

      }
    }
  }


}

function order_params(i, loop, members, teams, ignoreTeams){
  for (var x = 0; x < members.length; x++){

    if (!members[x].assigned && members[x].email != members[i].email && members[x].city == members[i].city  && (!checkTeams(members[x].team, teams) || ignoreTeams)) {
      if (members[x].choice1 == members[i].choice1 && loop < 3) {

        members[x].assigned = true;
        teams.push(members[x].team);
        return members[x].name
      } else if (members[x].choice2 == members[i].choice1 && loop >= 3 && loop < 6) {

        members[x].assigned = true;
        teams.push(members[x].team);
        return members[x].name

      } else if (members[x].choice3 == members[i].choice1 && loop >= 6 && loop < 9) {

        members[x].assigned = true;
        teams.push(members[x].team);
        return members[x].name

      } 
    }
  }

}
//Checks for duplicate teams in the group
function checkTeams(member_t, teams){
  for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
    if (member_t == teams[i]){

      return true; 
    }
  }
}
//Converts the data from the Sheet into Person objects.
function Person(email, name, team, city, choice1, choice2, choice3, driver){
  this.email = email;
  this.name = name;
  this.team = team;
  this.city = city;
  this.choice1 = choice1;
  this.choice2 = choice2;
  this.choice3 = choice3;
  this.driver = driver;
  this.assigned = false; //Assigned = true means the Person is already in a group

}
```

As you see I'm not using the field Driver, so you can make a condition in case you see too many groups without drivers, or change the members manually. If this is a serious problem, I will modify the code.